# Concatenating an API URI with values from a Google Sheet

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently, I am working with a google sheet using gscript, and I am trying to input data into the cells based on the value within column A of the sheet. The data is pulled through fetching the URI and I am trying to concatenate the URI with the ID located in Column A of the Google Sheet.

```
 var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("MYAPI + JOBID + TOKEN");
  

  var content = res.getContentText();

  var json = JSON.parse(content);

  Logger.log(content)

  // Users Name //
  

  var dispatches = json["dispatches"]["items"];

  var lastItem = dispatches.pop();

  var dName = lastItem.vehicle.driver.contact.name

  Logger.log(dName);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.getRange(2,3).setValue([dName]);

 // Pickup and Drop Off Information // 
 var task1timeframeBy = json["tasks"]["items"][0]["timeframe"]["by"]
 var task3timeframeBy = json["tasks"]["items"][2]["timeframe"]["by"]


 var task1Date = new Date(task1timeframeBy).toDateString()
 var task3Date = new Date(task3timeframeBy).toDateString()

 var task1Time = new Date(task1timeframeBy).toTimeString()
 var task3Time = new Date(task3timeframeBy).toTimeString()

 Logger.log(task1Date)
 Logger.log(task3Date)

  Logger.log(task1Time)
 Logger.log(task3Time)


 // Address Information //

var task1Address = json["tasks"]["items"][0]["zone"]["address"]
var task1Longitude = json["tasks"]["items"][0]["zone"]["coords"]["lon"]
var task1Latitude = json["tasks"]["items"][0]["zone"]["coords"]["lat"]

var task3Address = json["tasks"]["items"][2]["zone"]["address"]
var task3Latitude = json["tasks"]["items"][2]["zone"]["coords"]["lat"]
var task3Longitude = json["tasks"]["items"][2]["zone"]["coords"]["lon"]

Logger.log(task1Address)
Logger.log(task1Longitude)
Logger.log(task1Latitude)

Logger.log(task3Address)
Logger.log(task3Longitude)
Logger.log(task3Latitude)

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.getRange(2,4).setValue([task1Latitude]);

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.getRange(2,5).setValue([task1Longitude]);

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.getRange(2,6).setValue([task3Latitude]);

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.getRange(2,7).setValue([task3Longitude]);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.getRange(2,8).setValue([task1Time]);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.getRange(2,9).setValue([task3Time]);

  } }
```

The values located in column A are supposed to concatenate with the URI to pull different values and loop through the cells for input.

What I can not figure out is how to concatenate the URI with a variable, or loop through the cells to input the data requested. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's certainly better ways, but since the core of your question seems to be about iterating through column A data and builind the URL, here's one (food for thought)...
It's a bit hard without more information on your context, but this would be the approach I'd take:

```
const data = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('SheetName').getRange("A2:A").getValues();

let JOBID = '';
let APIdata = [];
for (let a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
    JOBID += data[a]
    URL = "MYAPI" + JOBID + "TOKEN"
    //Do the API call, but you'd have to check for their quota and set an interval maybe to meet their demand. 
    //Store the data into an array, so you can place the data into the defined range later
}
```

Comment: @Tree, You ```push``` the results into an array and use ```setValues()``` to put it where you want. Something like: ```sheet.getRange(rowNumber,ColNumber,array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array)```

Comment: I am converting the information I pull into JSON. Then as you can see in my above code I have placed it in the correct ranges to test it out for a single order ID that I was testing in the original fetch. Will the above code you posted work to loop through each cell in each column that contains an ORDER ID and place the values in them?

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much @santosONit - You have been wonderful!!!!

Comment: @Tree, That part deals with that range's values. You'd have to get the range as rangeList and loop through it setting the value, but this is advisable to set the values at once - in that case, converting the data into an array and using the piece shared in the comment above. I'm afraid that without more details and my limited knowledge, I can't go any further than that. Maybe, you should create another question with your current difficulty.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm usually on the other side of the question (still a beginner).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71278583/how-to-iterate-through-cells-in-google-sheets-and-input-values-fetched-and-parse